# How to find the repository containing a certain package

Tags: linux, repository, package

I am talking about a package **you do not currently have**.

For instance in my case I have to install `libsdl-gfx1.2-dev`, but it shows

> Unable to locate package

so obviously i need to add a repository to my sources. But I do not know which repository is that in, so the question is: how to find that repository?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "Linux" isn't uniform, definitely not in the package repos scene. From the package name, I'm guessing you're on a Debian/Ubuntu-based system. A quick Google search indicates that the package in question is in the [Universe] repo on Ubuntu, which IIRC is enabled by default.

Check your software-properties-gtk (or /etc/apt/sources.list) and enable that repo, then do an apt-get update (with root/sudo of course).

Comment: So you say there is no other way than googling it?

Comment: What I'm saying is: On Debian/Ubuntu, if you haven't subscribed to a repo, your package manager (apt) doesn't have info about that repo. That is all.

Comment: Awkay, thank you. But I will leave the question open in case someone comes up with something else. {: